# Error in edit form; Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, edit

I'm having this error.

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$fname

Filename: views/view_editstud.php

Line Number: 60

This is my view:

```
     <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>site/update_stud">

            <table>

                <?php foreach ($user->result() as $row) { ?>

                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Enter your first name</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="fname" size="20" value="<?php echo $row->fname; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Enter your last name</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lname" size="20" value="<?php echo $row->lname; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Enter your contact number</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="contact" size="20" value="<?php echo $row->contact; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Enter your address</th>
                    <td><textarea name="address" rows="5" cols="20"><?php echo $row->address; ?></textarea></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" />
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" /></td>
                </tr>

                <?php } ?>

            </table>
```

This is my Controller:

```
 public function edit($id) {

    $this->load->model('stud_model');

    $data['title'] = "edit";

    $data['user'] = $this->stud_model->getById($id);

    $this->load->view('view_editstud', $data);

}
```

This is my Model:

```
 public function getById($id) {

    $query = $this->db->get_where('students', array('ID'=>$id));

    return $query;
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: print($row) and check $fname index is available or not
this problem is cause by if only this index is not available

Answer (score 0):

```
print($row)
```

and check $fname index is available or not in array  this problem is cause by if only this index is not available

Comment: put it in view to check 
after  <?php foreach ($user->result() as $row) { ?>

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Filename: views/view_editstud.php

Line Number: 58

Comment: Put this `print_r($row);exit;` `before` `<?php foreach ($user->result() as $row) { ?>`